# How to prove the follwing conclusion?

Tags: calculus, limits, analysis

$
x_{0}=1,x_{n}=x_{n-1}+\cos{x_{n-1}}
$

Prove:$$x\to0,x_{n}-\frac{\pi}{2}=o(\frac{1}{n^n})$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Introduce $y_n = x_n - \frac{\pi}{2}$. Then $y_{n+1} = y_n - \sin(y_{n-1})$. 
With a Taylor expansion : $|x - \sin(x)| \leq \frac{1}{2} |x|^2$. Thus $|y_{n+1}|\leq \frac12 |y_n|^2$. Then you can conclude by induction.

Comment: Nice answer to a not nice question :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer